# Finding item without using primary key

Tags: scala, annotations, amazon-dynamodb

I try to lookup a user (username+password) in a dynamodb table using the username, the userid (int) is the primary key so getitem works:

```
val user = Try(table.getItem("userid",2233))//this works
```

Finding a user (to validate the password) using the username does not work however, I have tried this

I have a companion object:

```
object Authentication {
  @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "users")
  case class User(username: String, passwordMd5: String)
  ...
}
```

And try to scan() using this:

```
val scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
scanExpression.addFilterCondition("username",
  new Condition()
    .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS("some_username")))`
```

but this gives me the following error:

`com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: Class class Authentication$User$ must be annotated with interface com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable`

what do I need to fix this?

Solution (rewrite):

```
val client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new  ProfileCredentialsProvider())
client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.XXX))
val dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client)
val table = dynamoDB.getTable("users")
val index = table.getIndex("username-index")

val spec = new QuerySpec()
  .withKeyConditionExpression("username = :v_username")
  .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
  .withString(":v_username", username))

val items = index.query(spec)

val iterator = items.iterator()
val user = Try(iterator.next())
```

The catch was to use **index.query(spec)** NOT **table.query(spec)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need a bit more information on how your table is set up to answer the question.

1. Do you have other, non-primary, indices?
2. Do you use a primary key? Or primary+range?

In order to look up a user based on a key that isn't their primary key:

1. You can add a secondary index
2. Do a scan operation and filter out matching results manually
3. Add a range key (i.e. their username)

Comment: I tried using the index that was on the username, and that worked, thanks.